# Inverse of Topping's diameter estimates

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Topping's diameter estimates is

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional  closed, connected manifold smoothly immersed in $\mathbb R^N$, where $N\ge n+1$. Then the intrinsic diameter and the mean curvature $H$ of $M$ are related by 
>   $$
> \operatorname{diam}(M)\le C(n)\int_M |H|^{n-1}
> $$

I feel there should be some  lower estimation of $\operatorname{diam}(M)$ has liking form, since obviously, we have 
$$
\frac{1}{\max\limits_{M} |A|} \le \operatorname{diam}(M)
$$
although it is very rough, it means there should be some lower estimation. What theory describe this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_r$ be the smallest sphere of radius $r$ which contains $M$. Then the sphere touches $M$ at $x\in M$. At this point we have 
$$ |A(x)| \ge |A_r(x)|= \frac{n}{r},$$
(here $A_r$ is the second fundamental form of $S_r$). Thus 
$$ |A(x)| r \ge n\Rightarrow  \max|A|\operatorname{diam}(M) \ge 2n.$$

Comment: Do you know other low estimation ?